# Load CSS files instead of inline css for verse on prem customizations

Tags: css, json, lotus-domino, ibm-domino

We need to customize IBM Verse on prem for our corporate design. [The documentation show](https://ibmverse.github.io/verse-developer/tutorials/#css-extension) how to add customized inline css. But that's not maintainable for larger customizations. I want to load css files, that could be generated by sass for keeping development [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

I tried the following in the example from the official docs:

```
[
  {
    "name": "CSS Extension Sample",
    "description": "The sample shows how to customize Verse UI",
    "title": "CSS Extension Sample",
    "extensions": [
      {
        "type": "com.ibm.verse.ext.css",
        "name": "CSS extension sample",
        "payload": {
          "url": "{extensionPath}/samples/test.css"
        }
      }
    ],
    "services": ["Verse"]
  }
]
```

And I also did some experiments with [css import](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/@import) like this:

```
"payload": {
  "css": "@import url('{extensionPath}/samples/test.css');"
 }
```

with corresponding include of the file in `manifest.json`

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["page.js", "applications.json", "style.css"]
```

But `test.css` doesn't get loaded. The code itself works when using inline css:

```
"payload": {
  "css": ".ics-scbanner {background-color:green!important;}"
}
```

How can I load the css file instead of inline css?

Comment: @import is an sass command not a css command!

Comment: @Wimanicesir No, it's also CSS, see [CSS @import documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_import_rule.asp). But an `@import` directive [exists in SASS, too.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import).